# Spring XD stream that responds to an HTTP POST

Tags: spring-xd

I would like to create a stream in Spring XD that starting with an HTTP source would use the result of the stream execution as the body of the response.

In the following example, I would like to know if there is anything I could use as sink after I upper case in the transformer so that the body of the response of the original http post is that upper cased entity.

```
 stream create --name httptest --definition "http | transform --expression=payload.toUpperCase() | ??" --deploy
```

Currently, when I use it, putting the log module as the sink, the returned body is null.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; that is not currently supported; the stream is a one-way street.

You can use a stand-alone [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/), or [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl) app (perhaps a [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) app which provides a fast on-ramp with the web and integration starters) to provide that functionality.